# Search for a particular node using child node in xml java using DOM parser

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have the following XML structure

```
<CodeSnippet>
  <Code>
        <Tag></Tag> 
        <Title></Title>  
        <Snippet></Snippet>
 </Code>
```

I would like to search for specific node based on "Title" and update the "Snippet" value of that node.

The XPath i have used is "/Code[Title/text()='" + getTitle + "']". But, i am unable to get the Title node. Someone, please correct my xpath i am using.

Answer (score 1):

This one works for me:

```
/CodeSnippet/Code[Title[text()='" + getTitle + "']]/Snippet
```

For deleting a node:

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0440__XML/Removetheelementfromparent.htm http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-modify-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Comment: But, with this how do i update the Snippet Value. i tried storing the result to Node and access the Node value and update but didn't work for me.

Comment: 1. Thats a different question. 2. I can't answer that if I don't know what lib you're using.

Comment: I am using DOM Parser in Java with XML version 1.0

Comment: Silly me. I need to read titles again. Take a look here: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0440__XML/Removetheelementfromparent.htm